# How can I compare two columns values and apply conditional formatting on one of the columns based on both columns values?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-formatting

I have a data frame with scores for Q2, Q3 and Q4. If Q4's score is greater than Q3, I'd like to color the cell green. If Q4's score is less than Q3, I'd like to color the cell red. If Q3 and Q4 have the same score, I'd like to leave the cell white.

Here's the data and what I attempted to do

```
scores = pd.DataFrame({
    'Market': ['AL', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR', 'AR'], 
    'Health Plan': ['HP1', 'HP1', 'HP2', 'HP3', 'HP4'],
    'Network': ['Medicare', 'Ambetter', 'Medicaid', 'Medicare', 'Medicare'],
    'Q2': [72,51,49,70,62], 
    'Q3': [72,60,59,75,55],
    'Q4': [84,72,75,73,62]})


def color_cells(val):
    color = 'green' if val > scores['Q3'] else 'red' if val < scores['Q3'] else 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

scores.style.applymap(color_cells, subset='Q4')
print(scores)
```

And this is the error I am getting

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `np.select` to create a style array based on the conditions then `apply` the style array on the column `Q4`

```
colors = np.select(
    [scores['Q4'] > scores['Q3'], scores['Q4'] < scores['Q3']], 
    ['background: green', 'background: red'], 'background: white'
)

scores.style.apply(lambda s: colors, subset='Q4')
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Shubham. Works exactly the way I needed it to